# actionscript 3 code use in php?

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, filter, splice

I know actionscript 3 but dont know php
How do I use the following actionscirpt 3 codes on the php?

1.

```
var items:Array = [{name:"Hasan",age:30,{name:"Ahmet",age:20}];

items.splice(0,1);

result items =  [{name:"Ahmet",age:20}];
```

2.

```
var items:Array = [{name:"Hasan",age:30},{name:"Ahmet",age:20}];

for(var i:int = 0;i<items.length; i++}
{
    var tmp:Object = items[i];
    if(tmp.name == "Ahmet")
     {
          //found item
             return items[i];
      }
}

result return = {name:"Ahmet",age:20}
```

please help thanks

Comment: This may well be closed as *"Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service, what have you tried?"*

Comment: If you know AS3, learning PHP should be a breeze. Just look at the [manual](http://php.net). Specifically: [Arrays](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) and [foreach](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). SO is _not_ a free code translation service. I've been told that Google have a bunch of good links as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First php doesnt use {} for associative array, You use [].
Aswell associative arrayuse fat-arrow for key value instead of :

```
$items = [['name'=>"Hasan",'age'=>30],['name'=>"Ahmet",'age'=>20]];
```

Dont use var just $

```
for($i = 0;$i<items.length; $i++}
{
    $tmp = items[i];
    if(tmp['name'] == "Ahmet")
    {
        //found item
        return items[i];
    }
}

return ['name'=>"Ahmet",'age'=>20];
```